# ValueError Theano

Tags: theano, dbn

I am using a DBN classification code. I have *one* output value which is an integer(value of the output integer can be anything 110,12 etc). So basically I am trying to predict something using the classification code by setting its no_of_outputs=1. But I think no_of_output=1 is messing up with the code by giving the error: 
ValueError: y_i value out of bounds
Apply node that caused the error: CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias(_dot22.0, b, Elemwise{Cast{int32}}.0)
Inputs shapes: [(10, 2), (2,), (10,)]
Inputs strides: [(16, 8), (8,), (4,)]
Inputs types: [TensorType(float64, matrix), TensorType(float64, vector), TensorType(int32, vector)]
Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint of this apply node.

Kindly help me solve it.

Comment: Since you are doing [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis), (i.e your predictions are real values not class labels) you should not have any non-linearity at the output layer. The example code of [logistic regression](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/logistic_sgd.py) uses [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) which is sensible only for classification problems.

Comment: [This](http://danielhnyk.cz/predicting-sequences-vectors-keras-using-rnn-lstm/) and [this](http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) might be helpful. Also do take care of normalization etc.

Answer (score 0):

That's index value out of bound error, you should check your codes to make sure:

1. Your index value is not NaN
2. If your index value is a valid integer, you should check whether it's out of bound actually

You can print your value by compiling a theano function, which returns the parameters you want to print.